# Reshaping one column data frame into two columns in R

Tags: r

let say  I such a data frame(df) with chracters

```
head
---
a
b
c
d
e
f
```

I want to reshape df as

```
head1   head2
-----   -----
a        b
c        d
e        f
```

How can I do such a reshape without using any loop. I will be very glad for any help. Thanks a lot.

Comment: How many rows are there in the original dataset?  Do you want to split by 3?

Comment: @akrun, Row numbers are not fix. I have a lot of dataframes like df, where each dataframes' row numbers differ. I will reshape all of them into two columns as above in a loop.

Answer (score 3):

We can transpose (`t`) the dataset (which will be `matrix`), then call the `matrix` with the `ncol`, and reconvert it to `data.frame`

```
 as.data.frame(matrix(t(df1), ncol=2, 
          byrow=TRUE), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
 #  V1 V2
 #1  a  b
 #2  c  d
 #3  e  f
```